# Display mutiple query results in the django tables 2

Tags: django, django-tables2

I want to make multiple queries and display the results in a table, I'm using django-tables2.
Of course the results are related so they need to be in the same row.

Exemple : 2 models : devices and users, I want to display the devices and the persons using this device or the foreign key is in the person model

```
class Device(models.Model):
    iddevice = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) 
    typedevice = models.ForeignKey('Devicetype')

class Person(models.Model):
     idperson = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) 
     idpersondevice = models.ForeignKey('Device')
```

Comment: Can you show your models? I can't quite figure out what you want.

Comment: i want to display the devices and the persons using them in the same table

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I see. You need to write a custom Table class.

Make a file `tables.py`, and make sure you import your models and include the line `import django_tables2 as tables`.

```
class MyTable(tables.Table):
    idperson=tables.Column(accessor='idperson')
    iddevice=tables.Column(accessor='idpersondevice.iddevice')
    typedevice=tables.Column(accessor='idpersondevice.typedevice')

    class Meta:
        model=Person
```

then in your view:

```
table=MyTable(Person.objects.all()) #or filter it somehow
RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
```

And then pass that table to your template, where you can render it.

You'll need to customize your table (`MyTable`) to your liking, I've just given you the backbone. If you need more info, the docs are actually pretty decent. http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: I've been checking the docs all day, what you wrote doesn't do anything except changing the column name but no data displayed.And i want to display the devices not the person so the table will have device as model

Comment: Does `idperson` at least display data?

Comment: using device as model the problem is idperson which is not displayed otherwhise the problem is resolved

Comment: But the `device` cannot address the `person`, because the FK is in the `person` class. What is shown in the `typedevice` column with my suggested code?

Comment: i found this https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/issues/106 but it doesn't seem to work either

Comment: Can you tell me what the `typedevice` column looks like?